# Swift: Edit image taken from camera to fill a UIImageView

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimageview, scale

I have used a UIImageView that takes its image from the default camera app using UIPicker. But the image I am getting is too small to fit into the image view and if I use:

```
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```

While this indeed scales to fit the image view the picture looks like it has been mashed up and not particularly good. I was wondering if it was possible to scale the image up in such a way that the quality of the image does not get bad.

---

I am using Swift 1.2 and thanks for any help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with:

```
myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Camera images are usually bigger than a `UIImageView` on a device. To shrink them quickly to a visible size, the best way is to set the `.contentView` property of `UIImageView` to `.ScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: This works perfectly!! But just wondering will the image quality decrease or remain the same when scaled?

Comment: I think its decrease on any image when u scale it.

Answer (score 0):

try using `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill`
that fills the imageview by keeping the original aspect ratio. but that also means that parts of the image could be outside of the bounds of the imageview and therefore not visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a uiImagePickerController, you can adjust the quality with the property videoQuality : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/videoQuality

Juste set the quality type as TypeHigh